# Microsoft Graph Api - Create Education Assignment returns "20132" error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-edu

I want to create a specific class of assignments.

At Graph Explorer,

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/education/classes/{classId}/assignments
```

This request works well.

But in my C# code,

```
var assignInfo = new EducationAssignment
            {

                DisplayName = "test",
                
                DueDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2020-09-20T18:00:00Z"),
                Instructions = new EducationItemBody
                {
                    ContentType = BodyType.Html,
                    Content = "hi"
                },
                Status = EducationAssignmentStatus.Draft,
                AllowStudentsToAddResourcesToSubmission = true,
                
                AssignTo = new EducationAssignmentClassRecipient
                {

                },
                Grading = new EducationAssignmentPointsGradeType()
                {
                    MaxPoints = 100
                },
                CreatedDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2020-09-20T12:00:00Z"),
                AssignDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2020-09-20T13:00:00Z"),
                AssignedDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2020-09-20T13:00:00Z"),
                
                CloseDateTime = null,
                
                AllowLateSubmissions = true
                
            };

             await graphClient.Education.Classes[pClassId].Assignments
                .Request()
                
                .AddAsync(assignInfo);
```

It occured error:

```
{"Code: 20132\r\nMessage: The content of the request is invalid. Common causes are an invalid Content-Type header or no content in the body.\r\nInner error:\r\n\tAdditionalData:\r\n\tdate: 2020-09-20T07:25:14\r\n\trequest-id: d2181119-9116-4f1d-9ed4-d007e2e406d0\r\n\tclient-request-id: d2181119-9116-4f1d-9ed4-d007e2e406d0\r\nClientRequestId: d2181119-9116-4f1d-9ed4-d007e2e406d0\r\n"}
```

Why is this happening? I've been thinking and trying all day.

I tried

```
 await graphClient.Education.Classes[pClassId].Assignments
                .Request()
                .Header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .AddAsync(assignInfo);
```

But there was the same error.

If only the displayname element was requested, the results were the same.

The Permissions has been dealt with.
EduAssignments.ReadWriteBasic, EduAssignments.ReadWrite.. etc
And the dll(NuGet pakage) is also prepared in beta version.

I referred to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/educationclass-post-assignments?view=graph-rest-beta).

I'm desperate for help..
Thanks.

Comment: Was the class created via Teams or via Graph?

Answer (score 0):

adding this `assignInfo.ODataType = null;` fixes the problem.

Comment: Consider adding some more explanation, like *where* to add that code and how/why it fixes the problem.